# Counting the number of lines in a .txt file in c

Tags: c, memory-management

I have a processes.txt file that contains details about incoming processes like so,

```
0 4 96 30
3 2 32 40
5 1 100 20
20 3 4 30
```

I wanted to find the number of lines in this file. How can that be done?

I tried this code, but it always returns the number of lines as 0

```
char c;
int count = 0;
// fp is the pile pointer
for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) 
        if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline 
            count = count + 1;
```

Comment: `c` **must** be `int`

Comment: Since the `EOF` is `int` (its value being `0xFFFFFFFF`).

Comment: @pmg I am still getting a value of 0 for the number of lines even after changing the `char c` to `int c`

Comment: Have you done something else with your file after opening it? As @pmg points out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62059193/2513200), the file pointer may not be at the start of the file in this case.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger? Or commenting out the `if` - does this change the result?

Comment: On you running on Linux or Windows platform? Can you open your text file in a hex editor and confirm that there is indeed character 0xA in the file for newline?

Comment: Show a [MCVE], maybe the file was not correctly opened, or you did some other things before the code you show, who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the `char` that should be an `int` your code is more or less fine. The problem is somewhere in the code you didn't show.

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE* fp = fopen("processes.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("Could not open file.");
    return 1;
  }

  int c;    // this must be an int
  int count = 0;

  for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
    if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline 
      count = count + 1;

  printf("The file has %d line(s)\n", count);

  fclose(fp);
}
```

However if the last line of the file does not end with a `\n`, it is not counted.

Answer (score 1):

Please, read [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

In order to test your program snippet, I first had to complete your fragment of code in order to make it compilable.  Probably your error has gone with that modifications, as my run of it shows (over your input text) this output:

## pru.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char c;
        int count = 0;
        FILE *fp = stdin; // most probably your error is
                          // related to this initialization.

        // fp is the pile pointer
        for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) 
                        if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline 
                                count = count + 1;
        printf("%d\n", count);

        return 0;
}
```

and running it:

```
$ pru <<EOF
0 4 96 30
3 2 32 40
5 1 100 20
20 3 4 30
EOF
4
$ _
```

Which is the correct answer.

Despite of this, your program fragment, shows a *non visible error*, as you have been told in the comments to your question:  type of `c` variable should be `int` and not `char`, but why?

Because `char` is the type you want to receive, all available values are possible, so to indicate that **some special condition** has been detected in your file (the end of the data in the stream, or `EOF` is not one of those values, but a special condition) *one extra value is needed*, so making the type `char` insufficient to include all possible return values from `fgetc(3)`.  This is the reason to make `fgetc(3)` function to return an `int`.

Check the documentation of `fgetc(3)` as your program works almost fine, while you have to be given a reason of why:

When the program reads a character, it is mapped into the `int` values `0` to `255`, so all different bytes convert as positive integer values, while normally (almost every implementation does) `EOF` is mapped into the integer value `-1`.  What is happening here is that all your values are converted into a `char`, making `EOF` **to be mapped into one of those `0` to `256` values** (which one is dependent on the implementation, but normally it is the value `255` ---or `-1` if `char` happens to be signed) so:

- in case your `char` type is represented as a two's complement type (`signed`) your values `0` to `255` are mapped into `0` to `127` and `-128` to `-1`, and the `EOF` value is mapped to some of them (mostly `-1`).
- in case your `char` type is represented as an unsigned type, your values `0` to `255` are mapped into `0` to `255` and the `EOF` value is mapped to one of them (most probably `255`)
- it doesn't matter which value the `EOF` is converted to, as you make your comparison in a coherent type system, so the *converted* `char` value is compared with the *converted* `EOF` value making that `EOF` is converted into the converted value of `EOF`.  But this makes another `char` value to happen to show the same behaviour, making that one such charater on input will be interpreted as `EOF`, and will  make your program to stop prematurely.

In both cases above, if a byte with the same *mapped-to* value of `EOF` is input, your program will finish, believing that it has reached the end of the file, and your count will be erroneous.  This is not the case here, but you can get a surprise with one file that has such a character.

So your final program (corrected) would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int c;
        int count = 0;
        FILE *fp = stdin;

        // fp is the pile pointer
        for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) 
                        if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline 
                                count = count + 1;
        printf("%d\n", count);

        return 0;
}
```

Before terminating, I'll recommend to use a `while` loop, as it is a frequently used idiom in C to produce more compact form of your loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int c;
        long count = 0;
        FILE *fp = stdin; /* probably you dont have intialized this
                           * field in your code, but who knows, if 
                           * you have not posted a complete 
                           * sample */

        // fp is the pile pointer
        while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) 
              if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline 
                 count++; // this is another  frequently used idiom :)

        printf("%d\n", count);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your file is at the end or in error when you do this?? And you need to start at the beginning

```
int c;                            // c must be int
int count = 0;
// fp is the pile pointer

rewind(fp);                       // back to beginning, clear error

for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) 
        if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline 
            count = count + 1;
```

Comment: or he has simply not checked the `fopen(3)` return status and it trying `fgetc(NULL)` instead.  Who knows?